# DotNet Core Dependency Injection Multiple Projects

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, shared-libraries, blazor

I am building a Blazor WASM application.

The application is working but I am now looking to split the project into sensible self contained projects but having a problem working out how to implement the dependency injection without creating a circular dependency between projects.

```
Projects:
App.Client - UI Razor Pages
App.Server - Main project, controllers, defines interfaces
App.Shared - Shared models between Client & Server
App.Data - Implements repositories, unit of work, Db Context, migrations
```

The problem I am having is that the App.Data project has a dependency on the App.Server project to implement the interfaces it requires, but then I am not sure how to configure the dependencies in the startup.cs file in the App.Server project as this cannot have a dependency on the App.Data project.

[image]

Comment: Typically you'd put your interfaces in a domain layer, so App.Domain. App.Data would depend on App.Domain and App.Server would also depend on App.Domain. Your app.server can then also refer to app.Data in order for you to do your registrations (this is ok). Or you could use reflection as a way of registering the services without App.Server referring to App.Data.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that App.Domain wouldn't depend on anything. All dependencies would point inward.

Comment: I like the [Onion View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up combining the two comments to implement a Clean Architecture structure modified for the Blazor WASM application.

Adding a Core project, defining the interfaces, and Infrastructure project implementing infrastructure interfaces such as the database. Server then has dependencies on these 2 projects which makes sense.

Startup then configures the interfaces via DI, using the appropriate implementations either in Core or Infrastructure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Test.Models;
using Test.Models.Data;

namespace Test
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("database"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Test")));
            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            ...
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Project structure**

[image]